# Where are the Life Gems in Stage 1-3 (The Dead Bog)

Tags: castlevania-lords-of-shadow

In *Castlevania: Lords of Shadow*, the Dead Bog is a branching stage that has 4 Life Gems hidden in it.  I've found 3 of them, I haven't found the fourth one.  I've played through this stage at least 3 times.

Where are each of the life gems located in the Dead Bog, so I can figure out which one I missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the 4 gems are:

- Knight's corpse at the beginning
- Left Path: First bog path leads to the Knight
- After Second Gem: Proceed right till dry ground then run TOWARDS the camera (this is usually the one people miss)
- After Boss: its under the stairs.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I forgot to check these out yesterday (I was playing TF2 instead).  I'll try to check these out tonight after work.  I don't recall grabbing one after the boss, so it's probably the one I missed.

Comment: @Powerlord if my instructions aren't clear enough, let me know

Comment: I was missing the one on the stairs.  I didn't realize you could jump across before heading down... it would have helped if the Knight's body was flashing before I jumped over there. :/

Comment: @powerlord glad I could help